# Shortcut for declaring value on many inputs using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Help - my program has too many inputs, is there a way to make a script to make it shorter for shorter time?

PS: I reduced my code to only 5 inputs and value is only my problem (already did the type, name and id)

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="input1"  id="input1" value="<%=array[0].input1%>">
<input type="checkbox"  name="input2"  id="input2" value="<%=array[0].input2%>">
<input type="checkbox"  name="input3"  id="input3" value="<%=array[0].input3%>">
<input type="text"  name="input4"  id="input4" value="<%=array[0].input4%>">
<input type="text"  name="input5"  id="input5" value="<%=array[0].input5%>">
```

I always paste `<%=array[0].input%>` and edit it depending to its name. Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what problem you want solved. What does it mean to "...make it shorter for shorter time."? What does it mean that "...value is only my problem"?

Comment: How is `<%=array[0].input1%>` generated and rendered?

Comment: @AndrewWillems i have i think 50+ inputs, if i manually type it, it will cause  a long time.

Comment: @JohnCarloVelasquez: What are the common things among those inputs (rather than the tag ) .. because i noted the `type` also is not the same .

Comment: @guest271314 im using Node js with res.render('htmlname',{array:rows}) with rows function from select query

Comment: Are you asking for a way to make entering the code quicker? If you are, that depends on how you are entering the code (in an IDE? in a text editor?...what program are you using?). It also depends on what needs to be the same and what needs to be different for each row.

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI yes the type isnt the same. I think they dont have common things except they share with a same table database

Comment: Is the <% %> JSP or EJS?

Comment: @AndrewWillems yes, because in updating i use ajax, but in viewing i manually find them in the hrml code. Im using Notepad++ , i think there are no same types

Comment: Are you perhaps asking for a macro/script to, say, enter the same line 50 times, but with incrementing numbers for both `name="input#"` as well as `<%=array[0].input#%>` where the `#` is generated automatically?

Comment: @LarryLane im using EJS

Comment: No, it will depend on the name, for example name = dog then value= array[0].dog

Comment: So, if you enter `dog` into the `name`, then do you want `dog` to automatically appear after `array[0]` without having to do the typing manually?

Comment: Yes sir @AndrewWillems

Comment: I know how to do that in my IDE of choice, WebStorm. (In WebStorm they are called "live templates".) However, sorry, I'm not familiar with Notepad.

Comment: Its okay. Thanks!